# Which statistical test should I use if the assumptions of a 2-way ANOVA are not met?

Tags: regression, anova, nonparametric, normality-assumption, shapiro-wilk-test

My study design consists of two factors (one with 2 levels, the other with 6) and a continuous response variable. In order to analyze the influence of both factors on the explanatory variable I built a linear model in the following format:

`modela<-lm(response~factor1*factor2, data=dataset)`

I was going to run a 2-way ANOVA in order to test the significance of each of the explanatory variables however, upon evaluating the assumptions of this test, I found that the assumption of normality of residuals was violated (shown via a significant p-value from a Shapiro-Wilk test). All other assumptions (independent observations, no significant outliers, homogeneity of variances) were met.

Given this assumption violation is there a nonparametric alternative test that would be more appropriate to analyze my data. I have also read that transforming the data might help but I'm not sure a) if this would be appropriate and b) which transformations I should use.

Any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1 - Here is the Q-Q plot for my model:
[image]

Edit 2:

This is the output I got for the aligned ranks transformation ANOVA.

````
Call:
art(formula = Duration.egg ~ Temperature + Species + Temperature:Species, 
    data = egg.na.1)

Column sums of aligned responses (should all be ~0):
        Temperature             Species Temperature:Species 
                  0                   0                   0 

F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest (should all be ~0):
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 0.0000  0.0000  0.0000  0.4130  0.1609  2.2636 
Warning message:
In summary.art(x) :
  F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest are not all ~0. ART may not be appropriate.
```
````

Comment: It's usually better to look at histogram of residuals or a Q-Q plot to assess the normality of residuals, rather than a hypothesis test.  You might add these plots to your question to get some advice as to if the normality assumption is reasonably met.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I have added the Q-Q plot for my model

Comment: It's clear that your dependent variable is bounded on both the high and low ends, and that it is discrete.  I wonder if there is an appropriate generalized linear model that would work.  I'll be curious to hear other's more expert opinions.

Comment: If you want to go with a nonparametric model, aligned ranks transformation anova should work.  It's relatively easy in R.  With the caveat that I wrote it, there is an example here: [rcompanion.org/handbook/F_16.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_16.html)

Comment: @SalMangiafico Based on my research, doesn't an aligned ranks transformation ANOVA require a dependent variable that is ordinal? I apologize if this is a silly question as I have never heard of this test before

Comment: @SalMangiafico I tried to run an aligned ranks transformation ANOVA and I got the following error: ```Warning message: In summary.art(x) : F values of ANOVAs on aligned responses not of interest are not all ~0. ART may not be appropriate```. Also, the model wouldn't let me include my confounding variable unless I included all interactions with it.

Comment: Actually, from my understanding of the aligned ranks procedure, it isn't appropriate for ordinal data since the aligning procedure involves taking means and subtracting.  But I may be wrong. The following paper by Wobbrock et al. is fairly authoritative.  It does mention that the data can be ordinal or continuous.  In any case, it can be used with interval / continuous data. [faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/chi-11.06.pdf](https://faculty.washington.edu/wobbrock/pubs/chi-11.06.pdf)

Comment: In terms of the error, what's the output if you just call e.g. `model` ?

Comment: Another nonparametric analysis for a two-way factorial design is the Scheirer–Ray–Hare test.  Again with the caveat that I wrote it, that analysis is discussed here: [rcompanion.org/handbook/F_14.html](https://rcompanion.org/handbook/F_14.html)

Comment: But that being said, an OLS model (`lm()`) may be fine in your case, practically speaking, or you might use a permuation anova, or another analysis.  Again, I'd be interested to hear others' more expert opinions on your specific case.

Comment: @SalMangiafico I have added the output for my art ANOVA

Comment: I'm not familiar enough to render a judgment on that check from the ARTool package, but given that it's giving you that warning, and that---from playing around with some other examples--- an F value of 2 seems relevantly different from 0, my guess would be to not use that procedure.

Comment: Given that the nature of the non-normality is light-tailed, I don't see any need to use ranks. The ordinary methods will likely work just fine, with  good level and power properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the discussion in the comments largely addresses the question.  Here are a few points.

- Residuals for an ordinary least squares regression (OLS) don't need to be perfectly normal. On the one hand, nothing in the real world has a perfectly normal distribution.  But also, OLS regression is somewhat robust to deviations from normality.
- The data in this case appear to be discrete and bound on the upper and lower end.  I don't know if I would recommend OLS in this case. My interpretation of the q-q plot is that the residuals are symmetric with light tails.  OLS regression may be okay in this instance.  I don't know.
- A traditional nonparametric test for a two-factorial anova is the Scheirer–Ray–Hare test.  This test is sometimes criticized.  Also, there may not be a clear method for conducting post-hoc tests in all cases.  There also may situations (unbalanced designs, small sample size) where the test may not be ideal.
- A more contemporary nonparametric method is the aligned ranks transformation anova (ART anova).  In the current implementation in R, there are methods for post-hoc analysis and effect size. However, it is advised to research situations in which the method may not perform well.
- There are other methods that may be applicable, like permutation anova or quantile regression.